# CSS "Content" Property, can you concatenate text out of 2 parts?

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding CSS text concatenation.

I have a `<select>` dropdown with `<option>`s. I am using Select2 (js library) + HTML/CSS, I have created a clickable element that lets you clear all selected options. For example, if I select option1 and option2, above them there will be an option to clear them all.

Like this:

```
[x Clear all]
[option1]
[option2]
```

I added custom CSS to the "X Clear all" element, and it is as follows:

```css
.select2-selection__clear:before {  
    background-color: #1ab394;           
    width: 100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: left;
    content: 'X Clear all'; 
    visibility:visible;
}
```

The issue that I have is that the 'X' is a bit too large, and I would like to make it smaller without making the 'Clear all' part smaller as well.

[image: Element UI]

To be more specific if now my element looks like this: 'X Clear all', can I make it like this: 'x Clear all', with a smaller text size for the 'X'?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter exists but I think it'd be much better to use a separate DOM element for the x so it can be styled independently (and not be read by screenreaders as part of the text.)

Comment: Possible approach: use one of `::before` and `::after` for **Clear all** and the other for **x**.

Comment: I would add that using pseudo element content for meaningful information like a button is plain wrong in term of accessibility. Pseudo element should be used only for decorative purposes.

Comment: Can you inject html into that widget?

Comment: As the x is purely a visual sign you could draw it in a background-image as a couple of linear-gradients instead of inserting it as a character. However, the 'clear all' text is not purely a visual sign, it should be read out by a screen reader - i.e. part of the clickable element itself as @amauryhanser says, not in a pseudo element.